# React Router - Sidebar Doesn't Work On All Pages

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have a sidebar implemented for navigation on two pages: Dashboard and Study.

The sidebar works as expected on the Dashboard page, directing me to the right page. On the Study page however, when clicking on one of the links, the URL changes but the view doesn't. It just stays at the same page, as if nothing happened. When I manually refresh, it works.

Since I'm using Redux as well for authentication purposes and for getting the logged in user id, every component which needs access to the store has a withRouter() export. But it still doesn't work.

Here is the relevant code:
**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div className="App">

            <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />

            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/signup" component={Register} />

            <Route path="/studies" component={SidebarDashboard} />
            <Route exact path="/studies" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="/studies/:id" component={Study} />

          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

**Sidebar.js**

```
class SidebarDashboard extends Component {
.
.
.

<Link to={'/studies/' + study.study._id}>
     <ListItem button>
           <ListItemText disableTypography inset primary={study.study.study_name} />
     </ListItem>
</Link>
.
.
.
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    userID: state.auth.user.id
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(SidebarDashboard));
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
.
.
.
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <HeaderDashboard />
                <Overview studies={this.state.studies} />
                <StudyList studies={this.state.studies} />
            </div >
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    userID: state.auth.user.id
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard));
```

**Study.js**

```
class Study extends React.Component {
.
.
.
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    userID: state.auth.user.id
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Study));
```

So basically I want to know how it's possible that on Dashboard the links work correctly and on Study the same links don't work. I'm baffled.
I mean, the SidebarDashboard component stays the same on both pages.

Comment: <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
This should be the last one

Comment: Why? I thought this is only relevant when using <Switch>?

Comment: You should arrange routes more specific first and rest later and `/` should always be in the last

Comment: ok, done, but didn't solve my problem.

Comment: why you have two same routes with different components?
<Route path="/studies" component={SidebarDashboard} />
            <Route exact path="/studies" component={Dashboard} />

Comment: Because the dashboard should be shown on every route with /studies and the Dashboard only exactly on /studies. So Sidebar on both Dashboard and Study to ensure navigation. That way it's the same Sidebar on both pages, otherwise (The sidebar is a collapsable list) the Sidebar is always in collapsed state when changing route. I want it to stay the same, like a normal navigation bar.

Comment: Then go for nested routing

Comment: ok, I look into it. I thought it'd work without nesting.